# Query all tables in a db and return all items that meet query

Tags: php, sql, html

I will have several tables in a sql db for a web site. We are selling jewelry and we have the tables set up by type: bracelets, ear drops, chains, pendents you get the idea. The items come in different types of metals and stones. Every table has the same columns. From the menu you can chose chains and you will get all the chains, from the sub menu you can chose 18,14 ct white or yellow gold, silver or base. I have this working fine. Now we want to set up a menu where a person can chose all the items that are 18 ct yellow gold or 14 ct white gold or silver and get all the items that are made with that choice of metal. This should be easy something like FROM *table(where it would search all the tables in a db) and return the items. Am I on the correct path or not even in the same solar system. Thanks Jim

Comment: This is bad design. You should have one table, and it should have a `type` column for chains, pendents, etc.

Comment: What type of database are you using, MySql, MS SQL, etc?

Answer (score 0):

As Justin said, you should have only one table.  One consideration that can help you decide whether different items fit in the same table is if they have the same columns.  Since you have the same columns for all four items, they are really the same entity, Jewelry.

Add a column for type.  Then when you want to display only bracelets, use "Where Type = "Bracelets".

Even better would be to have a second JewelryType table with an integer ID type to identify each type of Jewelry.

Comment: If you really want to stick with the four separate tables, you will need to union them together every time that you want all of them together.  Trust me, that will get old quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Get all the tables from the DB using `mysql_query(show tables from db_name;)` and then programatically generate and execute queries to fetch the desired rows from all the tables.